# AWS volumes and AMI without a specific tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, aws-cli

To find list of instances without tag "Environment", I used the following command.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[?Instances[?length(Tags[?Key=='Environment']) == `0`]].Instances[].InstanceId' --output text
```

Now, how to find the list of volume-Id doesn't have a specific tag? Suppose some of my volumes have tag "Environment". When executing a command the result should contain volume-Ids without the tag Environment.

Similarly, I need to list the AMI and snapshot also.

Comment: you can try jq if you want to stick with command line if not python is better

Answer (score 1):

It would be rather challenging to fit this into an [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command.

Instead, use this Python script:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = client.describe_volumes()

# Find volumes that do not have an 'Environment' Tag
for volume in response['Volumes']:
  if 'Environment' not in [tag['Key'] for tag in volume['Tags']]:
    print volume['VolumeId']
```

Answer (score 0):

I listed all the instances id's into a file(file A). And then listed instance id's with tag 'Environment' into another file(file B). And then I find the differences between these two files(instance id's listed in file A but not in file B).